# how to print multiple html pages with different headers and footers

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a 'master' report made with react components that I need to print. It consists of multiple reports with different headers and footers. Is it possible to do, and if so what would be the best approach? [how i'd like it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCCBv.png)

Tried `position:fixed` for header and footer, works fine for header, only on single page reports, on multi page reports content of the page overlaps the footer of the same page as well as the header of the next page. Footer (with same approach as header) is a complete mess, prints all footers on each page.

Found this article https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a but it looks like it'll work for multipage documents with same header/footer.

UPDATE :
Tried playing around with `@page margin` (documentation: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#margin-at-rules), but those rules set 'hard' margins and things like negative margins/paddings or absolute positioning doesn't work beyond the content box.

```css
.report-page-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0.55in;
  break-after: page;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  h3 {
    background-color: #e1efc3;
    color: #003250;
    padding: 0.45in 0.2in;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 85%;
    position: fixed;
  }
  h4 {
    color: #003250;
  }
  .row {
    margin: 1.8in 20px 20px 20px;
  }
  ul {
    margin-top: 0.5in;
    margin-right: 0.5in;
  }
  footer {
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    print-footer-counter::after {
      counter-increment: row;
      content: "Page " counter(row) ": ";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="report-page-wrapper">
  <h3>Report 1 Header</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>Inner Header 1</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h4>Inner Header 2</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>Footer 1</li></ul>
  </footer>
</div>

<div class="report-page-wrapper">
  <h3>Report 2</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4>Inner Header 2</h4>
      <li>Some stuff</li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4>Inner Header 2a</h4>
      <li><b>1</b>&nbsp;q</li>
      <li><b>2:</b>&nbsp;w</li>
      <li><b>3:</b>&nbsp;e"</li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <ul>
      <li>Footer 2</li></ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```